Is there an easy way to batch the change of StyleSheet in 120 notebooks
At one point in the past I believed that a style sheet colocated with a notebook would not require a path.  For example, if my notebook resided in the same directory as this style sheet, the style sheet would be found by the filename alone:
"/D:/code/mma/review/review-topics/Stylesheet-review-topics.nb"
Now I have 120 notebooks with the style sheet location hard-coded to a location on a Windows system, and I have moved to Linux.
Is there a way to set the StyleSheet in all 120 notebooks in a directory as a batch process?
I now put the style sheet in "$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/", so I hope to avoid this in the future.  I don't like that because then the style sheet has to be put into that location by anyone else who wants to use my notebooks, and it's harder to maintain backups.

All the guilty notebook files were named to match "review*.nb".  The notebook I ran the code from is in the same directory, and is named "manager.nb".  So it didn't work on itself.  It ain't pretty, but it (seems to have) worked.
setStyle[] := Module[{}
   , SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
   NotebookOpen[#, Visible -> False] & /@ FileNames["review*.nb"];
   Print[Options[#, StyleDefinitions]] & /@ Notebooks["review*.nb"];
   SetOptions[#, 
      StyleDefinitions -> "Stylesheet-review-topics.nb"] & /@ 
    Notebooks["review*.nb"];;
   Print[Options[#, StyleDefinitions]] & /@ Notebooks["review*.nb"];
   NotebookSave[#] & /@ Notebooks["review*.nb"];
   NotebookClose[#] & /@ Notebooks["review*.nb"]
   ];
setStyle[]
Edit to add.  The above code worked on my Linux system, but not on Windows.  The following works on both.  I have no explanation for the difference in behavior of NotebookOpen[] between the two implementations.  Very frustrating!

setStyle[] := Module[{}
   , Print@SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
   NotebookOpen[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], #}], 
      Visible -> False] & /@ FileNames["review*.nb"];
   Print[Options[#, StyleDefinitions]] & /@ Notebooks["review*.nb"];
   SetOptions[#, 
      StyleDefinitions -> "Stylesheet-review-topics.nb"] & /@ 
    Notebooks["review*.nb"];
   Print[Options[#, StyleDefinitions]] & /@ Notebooks["review*.nb"];
   NotebookSave[#] & /@ Notebooks["review*.nb"];
   
   NotebookClose[#] & /@ Notebooks["review*.nb"]
   ];
setStyle[]

